# Error en el formato de las fechas en los emails de Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy usando un plugin que se llama woocommerce delivery date que sirve para que los clientes puedan establecer una fecha y hora de entrega de sus pedidos.

El problema que estoy teniendo es que a la hora de enviar los emails de confirmación tanto al cliente como al vendedor, las fechas están aparecido en milisegundos.

Aquí en el resumen del pedido, la fecha para la llegada de este pedido (25/2/2023) aparece en el formato que he establecido:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en los correos de confirmación que nos llegan tanto al cliente como al vendedor, la fecha aparece en milisegundos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabría decirme lo que ocurre o en su defecto, por dónde debería empezar a investigar?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola InfiniteRoads, por lo que entiendo de lo que explicas, parece ser un problema de la aplicación, deberías comunicarte con el/los desarrollador/es, para ver que solución te pueden dar.

Comment: Buenas tardes @MarcePuente!! El desarrollador soy yo. Lo que necesito saber es en qué punto, fichero o función se inyectan los datos del pedido en el email. Gracias!

Comment: Hola, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ve el código de tu aplicación, al menos la sección donde haces en el envio, y donde se recibe.

Comment: Buenas!! Pues es que es es un flujo de compra normal, no hay nada modificado. Cuando se realiza una compra, se envía un email al cliente para decirle que su pedido está en marcha y otro email al vendedor para decirle que tiene un nuevo pedido. En ambos emails se pueden ver los datos del pedido. Estos datos son los datos personales del cliente y aquí, además se añaden dos campos nuevos que son la fecha y la hora de la recogida o llegada del pedido. De esto se ocupa el plugin...

Comment: Entonces el problema es que no sé en qué función o template se realiza ese gancho o hook para insertar la fecha y hora en el email.
Gracias!!

Comment: Te entiendo, en algún lugar de tu código, se crea el email, cuando se hace esto, en vez de pasar el objeto *Date* a texto, se lo manda como *Date*, no puedo decirte donde porque no veo tu código, pero ese es el problema, fijate antes de pasar la fecha al email, de convertirla a texto.